# C# catch exception value is null

Tags: c#, try-catch

I didn't think this was possible. The exception variable on the try/catch is null.
Anyone seen this before or know how to fix. I restarted and have the same issue. Only happens occasionally on a threaded call so I can't debug this if I can't see the exception.

[image]

```
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
          {
    #if DEBUG
            string debugPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\SPErrorLog.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "-----------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "RemoteSolve - " + url + "?token=" + token + "&sType=" + solveType + Environment.NewLine);
    #endif
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            try
            {
              
              using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), url + "?token=" + token + "&sType=" + solveType)) //user specifies the solver to use
              {
                var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                multipartContent.Add(new StreamContent(inStream), "file", "SomeGuidName");
                request.Content = multipartContent;

    #if DEBUG
                File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "MultipartContent created - File size" + insize + " streamPointer - " + inStreamPtr +   Environment.NewLine);
    #endif

                var task = Task.Run(() => httpClient.SendAsync(request));
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                try
                {
                  response = task.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
    #if DEBUG
                  File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "Exception in HTTP call - " + task.Status + " " + e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
    #endif
                }


    #if DEBUG
                File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "SendAsync done, response - " + response.StatusCode  + Environment.NewLine);
    #endif

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                  var responseContent = response.Content;

                  IntPtr stringPointer = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                  retSize = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Length;

                  outStreamPtr = stringPointer;
                }
                else
                {
    #if DEBUG
                  File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "Bad call Response - " + response.StatusCode + Environment.NewLine);
    #endif
                  retSize = 0;
                }
              }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
    #if DEBUG
              File.AppendAllText(debugPath, "Exception - " + e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
    #endif
            }
```

Comment: are you stopped on the 'catch' line?  I think you have to step into the catch block for it to get the value.  If you are already in the block then not sure.

Comment: You should also benefit from async-await

Comment: It's not clear that `e` actually is `null`, it may be `class MyLyingException : Exception { public string ToString() => "null"; }`.   Try expanding the arrow to the left of `e` in the mouseover datatip.

Comment: It is stopped inside the try with breakpoint between the "if DEBUG" and "endif". I updated the Pic

Comment: Ok, that's really `null`.  Do you have (non-Microsoft) native DLLs running in the same process, that might be causing memory corruption?  You can also try setting your Exception settings to "Break when thrown" instead of waiting for the catch block to run.

Comment: Perfect, that did it Ben. It was my debugging log, I should have made the file write a thread safe section.  I guess throwing an exception in the "if DEBUG" block did it.